# SQL Query, Sum up entries bevore and after one specific

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I try to get the most type of a Entrie from a specific Type. To make it clear, i will start with the example. My column type is a foreign key in reality.

**Example:**

My counter table (~ 1.500.000 rows), it counts all seen cars at different traffic lights:

```
id, datetime, type, traffic_light_id
0, '09:59', 'red ford', 2
1, '10:00', 'black bmw', 1
2, '10:11', 'red ford', 1
3, '10:30', 'yellow ford', 1
4, '11:01', 'black bmw', 1
5, '11:09', 'red ford', 1
6, '11:18', 'green mercedes', 1
7, '11:20', 'black bmw', 2
8, '11:44', 'white renault', 2
9, '11:44', 'red renault', 1
```

i got an index on each column. id is the primary key.

**Needed:**

So what i like to get is a Result for 'black bmw' with traffic_light_id = 1.
The result should sum up all bevore and after the 'black bmw' seen types of cars.

The result should be:

```
count, type, traffic_light_id
2, 'red ford', 1
1, 'yellow ford', 1
```

**My bad Solution:**

So my solution till now was to iterate trough all counts in counter where type = 'black bmw' and traffic_light_id = 1.

For each count i get the bevore and after seen element with traffic_light_id also (that makes two querys in addition for each count) in my php script.

After that i group the result by the given car types in my array and count their frequency.

Is there any better solution for something like that? The best thing would be one sql query only!

Comment: Is your `id` column really starting with 0?

Comment: no not really, it is just an example...

Comment: "*sum up all before and after the 'black bmw' seen types of cars.*" isnt't that "sum up all all *except* the 'black bmw'"? Or do you mean "the one car *immediately* before or after the black bmw"?

Comment: i mean "the one car immediately before or after the black bmw" with traffic_light_id 1 for example

Answer (score 2):

I first understood that you want a simple group by:

```
select type, count(*) as totalseen,
       sum(case when traffic_light_id = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as SeenTrafficLight1
from t
group by type
```

If you really just want traffic light = 1, then use a `where` clause:

```
select type, traffic_light_id, count(*)
from t
where traffic_light_id  = 1
group by type
```

Bort, thank you for the clarification.  This makes the question much more interesting.

Here is how we do that using a correlated subquery.  Here is an example for the type before:

```
select typeBefore, count(*)
from (select t.*,
             (select type from t t2 where t2.datetime < t.datetime order by t2.datetime desc limit 1
            ) as typeBefore,
             (select type from t t2 where t2.datetime > t.datetime order by t2.datetime limit 1
            ) as typeAfter
      from t
     ) t
where type = 'black,bmw' and traffic_light_id = 1
group by typeBefore
```

The subquery is using the datetime to determine the before version.  If `id` is a primary key and ordered in the same way, you can use that.

Then the process is a little more complicated.  Here is one way to do it by cross joining to a table with two rows.  This makes it possible to group on `typeBefore` and `typeAfter` at the same time:

```
select (case when which = 'Before' then typeBefore else typeAfter end), count(*)
from (select t.*,
             (select type from t t2 where t2.datetime < t.datetime order by t2.datetime desc limit 1
            ) as typeBefore,
             (select type from t t2 where t2.datetime > t.datetime order by t2.datetime limit 1
            ) as typeAfter
      from t
     ) t cross join
     (select 'before' as which union all select 'after') const
where type = 'black,bmw' and traffic_light_id = 1
group by (case when which = 'Before' then typeBefore else typeAfter end)
```

Comment: May be misunderstanding, but I don't think this is what he wants.  I think given a car type and a light, he wants the count of cars that arrived immediately before and immediately after that car arrived at the light.

Comment: @Bort you are right, i am searching a result for 'black bmw' with traffic_light_id = 1 only

Comment: thank you, i am testing your suggestion! at all i have ~ 1.500.000 rows in my counter table. so the correlated subquery is still running :)

Comment: Hopefully you have an index on `datetime`, or this could take a long time.  The alternative of using `id` might be more efficient.  An index on `(datetime, type)` or `(id, type)` would be best.

Comment: I got an single index on each column. id is primary. wouldnt it be good to add an index on (datetime, type, traffic_light_id) ?

Answer (score 0):

its the count of the ones imediately after and before, right?

this is a good question...

(I did use this table variable to build my query, replace it for your table on the query or test with my variable)

```
    declare @T table(id int,[datetime] time,[type] varchar(max) ,traffic_light_id int)
    insert into @T (id,datetime,type,traffic_light_id)
    values
    (0, '09:59', 'red ford', 2)
    ,(1, '10:00', 'black bmw', 1)
    ,(2, '10:11', 'red ford', 1)
    ,(3, '10:30', 'yellow ford', 1)
    ,(4, '11:01', 'black bmw', 1)
    ,(5, '11:09', 'red ford', 1)
    ,(6, '11:18', 'green mercedes', 1)
    ,(7, '11:20', 'black bmw', 2)
    ,(8, '11:44', 'white renault', 2)
    ,(9, '11:44', 'red renault', 1)
```

maybe something like this would solve the problem?

```
select COUNT(*) as [count],OA.type,OA.traffic_light_id
        from @t T
        outer apply(select type,traffic_light_id 
                    from (select top 1 type,traffic_light_id 
                            from @T T_after
                            where T_after.datetime > T.datetime
                            order by T_after.datetime
                    )V_after
                    union all 
                    select type,traffic_light_id 
                    from (select top 1 type,traffic_light_id from @T T_before
                            where T_before.datetime < T.datetime
                            order by T_before.datetime desc
                    )V_before
        )OA
        where T.traffic_light_id = 1
        and T.type = 'black bmw'
        group by OA.type,OA.traffic_light_id
```